# Cómo generar PDF de un sistema web en PHP

Tags: php, html, fpdf, html2pdf

Cuento con un sistema web en PHP interactivo que contiene imágenes y tablas de datos traídos de Mysql así como tablas de texto y más. Necesito imprimir en PDF tal cual se muestra el sistema al momento de iniciar sesión, lo más practico para mí sería hacerlo a través de la función **window.print()** pero no puedo hacerlo debido a que hay elementos como el "header" y "footer" que no se tienen que mostrar en el PDF, así como elementos de inicio de sesión cómo "BIENVENIDO usuari@".

Me gustaría recibir algo de ayuda ya que he intentado con librerías como HTML2PDF o FPDF y no reconoce elementos como las tablas y las imágenes y esto me genera un error. Aquí dejo el código del sistema que quiero imprimir:

```
  <?php
  <tr>
  <td>Condiciones en el ambiente de trabajo</td>
  <td><?php echo round ($totalsiete['condiciones']); ?></td>
  <td><?php if($totalsiete['condiciones']<=3){
      echo "<img src='img/azul.png' style='width: 20%'>";
  }elseif($totalsiete['condiciones']>=3.1 && $totalsiete['condiciones']<=5){
      echo "<img src='img/verde.png' style='width: 20%'>";
  }elseif($totalsiete['condiciones']>=5.1 && $totalsiete['condiciones']<=7){
      echo "<img src='img/amarillo.png' style='width: 20%'>";
  }elseif($totalsiete['condiciones']>=7.1 && $totalsiete['condiciones']<=9){
      echo "<img src='img/naranja.png' style='width: 20%'>";
  }elseif($totalsiete['condiciones']>=9.1){
      echo "<img src='img/rojo.png' style='width: 20%'>";
  }else{
      echo "No hay datos";
  }
  ?></td>
  </tr><br>
  <td>
 <tr> </tr>
  <th scope="row"><?php if($final['calificacionFinal']<=20){
      echo "<img src='img/nulo.png'>";
  }elseif($final['calificacionFinal']>=20.1 && $final['calificacionFinal'] 
  <=45){
      echo "<img src='img/bajo.png'>";
  }elseif($final['calificacionFinal']>=45.1 && $final['calificacionFinal'] 
  <=70){
      echo "<img src='img/medio.png'>";
  }elseif($final['calificacionFinal']>=70.1 && $final['calificacionFinal'] 
  <=90){
      echo "<img src='img/alto.png'>";
  }elseif($final['calificacionFinal']>=90.1){
      echo "<img src='img/muyalto.png'>";
  }else{
      echo "No hay datos";
  }
  ?>
  </th>
  </td>
  ?>
```

Comment: se que tu duda iba por generar el pdf, pero queria aclararte que igual puedes marcar que zonas de tu html no quieres imprimir, en este post puedes ver mas documentacion: https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/htmlcss/how-to-print-a-specific-part-of-a-html-page-css-media-screen-print.html

Comment: ese es todo tu codigo para generar el pdf? si hay mas puedes publicarlo para poderte ayudar?

Comment: Agradezco tu aporte @JeanCarlosGarcia , no cuento con un código de generar PDF ya que como había mencionado no me funcionaba nada. Pero la información que me pasaste me resulto muy útil gracias.

Comment: Excelente... éxitos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto me resultó muy útil:

```
 ...
 <div class="noprint">
 page header
 </div>

 ...

 this part of the page contains the part we want to print, e.g. the form

 ...
 <div class="noprint">
 page footer
 </div>
 ...
```

Include CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

@media print
{
.noprint {display:none;}
}

@media screen
{
...
}

-->
</style>
```